# Как выделить текущий пункт меню?

Tags: css, меню

Надо добавить текущий пункт меню таким же как и при наведении, чтобы человек на сайте понимал на какой странице он находится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код меню:**

```
<nav id="primary-menu" class="clearfix">         
    <ul id="menu-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-22">
            <a href="#">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-menu-item menu-item-12">
            <a href="#">Англия</a>
        </li>
    </ul>                    
</nav>
```

**css**

```
#primary-menu {background-color:#2a2a2a; }
#primary-menu ul {margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; text-align:center; }
#primary-menu li {position:relative;  padding:16px 20px 10px 0 ;  font-size:16px; display:block;display:inline-block; }
#primary-menu li a {color:#ffffff; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:bold;}
#primary-menu li:last-child {padding-right:0;}
#primary-menu li a:hover {border-top: 5px solid yellow; padding-top: 13px;  color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;
```

Вот сам css код меню, сайт на wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#primary-menu li.current-menu-item a {
    border-top: 5px solid yellow;
    padding-top: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает

Comment: http://fangoal.ru/

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает ) Что бы я без вас делал :D